# Why does my ArrayList add elements itself on my fragment event?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

How i have said in my question i have a fragment with a list of check boxes and an ArrayList of items choosen (they are the labels of the check boxes). When the event of a check box is fired the fragment calls the method of the interface in the main activity but in it the list of items choosen has already the item in it, although there isn't in the entire code any method that can add items to it.

Here the code:

MainActivity :

```
package com.fp.testfragment1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.fp.testfragment1.MultiChoiceFragment.OnMultiSelectedListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMultiSelectedListener
{
    FrameLayout frameLayout1;
    FrameLayout frameLayout2;
    Button transitionButton;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    MultiChoiceFragment multiChoiceFragment;
    Boolean replace;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    ArrayList<String> mylis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = new ArrayList<String>();     
        mylis = new ArrayList<String>();    


        list.add("item1");
        list.add("item2");
        list.add("item3");
        list.add("item4");
        list.add("item5");

        transitionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.transitionButton);
        transitionButton.setOnClickListener(transitionListener);

        frameLayout1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);
        frameLayout1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frameLayout2);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() 
    {
        super.onStart();

        replace = false;
    }



    OnClickListener transitionListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            multiChoiceFragment = new MultiChoiceFragment(MainActivity.this, list, mylis, 8);

            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);

            if(replace)
            {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout1, multiChoiceFragment);    
            }
            else
            {
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout1, multiChoiceFragment);
                replace = true;
            }


            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

    };



    @Override
    public void onGroupMCheckListener(String itemName, Boolean checked, int nf) 
    {
        if(nf == 8)
        {
            //here i have the list already full


            // this is for debug
            mylis = mylis;

        }
    }

}
```

MultiChoiceFragment :

```
package com.fp.testfragment1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MultiChoiceFragment extends Fragment
{
    Context context;
    OnMultiSelectedListener mCallback;
    LinearLayout groupsListLinearLayout;
    TableRow congiungiTableRow;
    TextView groupsTextView;
    ArrayList<String> groups;
    ArrayList<String> groupsChoosen;
    int nFragment;

    public MultiChoiceFragment(Context context, ArrayList<String> groups, ArrayList<String> groupsChoosen, int nFragment)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.groupsChoosen = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.groups = groups;
        this.groupsChoosen = groupsChoosen;
        this.nFragment = nFragment;
    }


    public MultiChoiceFragment()
    {
        groups = new ArrayList<String>();
        groupsChoosen = new ArrayList<String>();
    }


    public interface OnMultiSelectedListener
    {
        public void onGroupMCheckListener(String itemName, Boolean checked, int nf);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try 
        {
            mCallback = (OnMultiSelectedListener) activity;
        } 
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnMultiSelectedListener");
        }

        context = activity;     


    }   

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        outState.putStringArrayList("groups", groups);
        outState.putStringArrayList("groupsChoosen", groupsChoosen);
        outState.putInt("nFragment", nFragment);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choice_fragment, container, false);

        groupsListLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.groupsLinearLayout);
        groupsTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.groupsTextView);
        congiungiTableRow = (TableRow)v.findViewById(R.id.congiungiTableRow);

        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            groups = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("groups");
            groupsChoosen = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("groupsChoosen");
            nFragment = savedInstanceState.getInt("nFragment");
        }

        refreshListGUI();

        return v;
    }


    public void refreshListGUI() 
    {       

        for(int a = 0; a < groups.size(); a++)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
            checkBox.setId(a);
            if(groupsChoosen == null || groupsChoosen.isEmpty() == true)
            {
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            else if(groupsChoosen.isEmpty() == false && groupsChoosen.contains(groups.get(a)))
            {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }

            checkBox.setText((String)groups.get(a));
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkBoxMItemListener);

            groupsListLinearLayout.addView(checkBox);
        }       


    }


    OnCheckedChangeListener checkBoxMItemListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            String groupC = buttonView.getText().toString();

            if(isChecked == true && groupsChoosen.contains(groupC) == false)
            {
                groupsChoosen.add(groupC);
                mCallback.onGroupMCheckListener(groupC, isChecked, nFragment);
            }
            else if(isChecked == false && groupsChoosen.contains(groupC) == true)
            {
                groupsChoosen.remove(groupC);
                mCallback.onGroupMCheckListener(groupC, isChecked, nFragment);
            }

        }

    };





}
```

PS. I use the nf in another project

Comment: There seems to be a general tendency that you can see some quite "magical" stuff whenever someone uses `ArrayList<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeClass>()` instead of `List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<SomeClass>();` and the same applies here for storing the reference to the Activity even though it can die and that's what onAttach() and getActivity() are for to begin with.

Comment: So what would you suggest to change?

Comment: Simple things, like not using a parametrized constructor on the Fragment because at recreation it will lose its parameters, use .setArguments(Bundle) instead. Don't send the Context, it can get a Context on its own. Use `List<Whatever> list = new ArrayList<Whatever>();` to use an interface as a static type, not the actual implementation. I am not sure what the error is, because I don't really understand what function runs when, what the result is supposed to be and what it actually is.

Comment: It doesn't work and gives the same issue. Other ideas?

Comment: specify the issues a bit more clearly with what is supposed to happen and what happens instead and where you think the error is

Comment: OK, when i'm in onGroupMCheckListener i should have mylis empty because there isn't any method in MainActivity which can change it (except the "mylis = mylis" instruction which i use for debug). Instead when i'm there mylis has an element. It should works that when i check or uncheck a checkbox it should add or remove from mylis the item given from the parameters but if there are elements before this it can't work.